# Remote Desktop in browser through Nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, openstack, rdp

My requirement is to develop a web page which shows the remote desktop I am connected to. The computer I am trying to connect is on the OpenStack cloud which has a static I.P(public I.P) and can be accessed by providing login credentials.

I don't mind if there is a need to add a plugin to my browser. Is there a tool or API to support this? Glad if there is a Node js solution for this.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried the **remote-control-server** package?. It enables you to control your PC from your web browser on your other PC or mobile device remotely. It also supports mouse movements, scrolling, clicking and keyboard input.

You can check it out here.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/remote-control-server

Hope this helps!